# How to get working this simple dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm a back-end developer, and I'm building a simple front for my project. For simplicity, I'm using a free template; you can find a online demo here:
http://demos.creative-tim.com/light-bootstrap-dashboard/dashboard

I need to implement a dropdown menu for language switch, so I tried to simply copy the HTML code:

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-absolute">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navigation-example-2">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="../dashboard.html">WELCOME</a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                            LANGUAGE
                            <b class="caret"></b>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Español</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Valencià</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="register.html">
                            Register
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

And then import all CSS and JS files that uses the online demo:

- bootstrap.min.css
- light-bootstrap-dashboard
- pe-icon-7-stroke.css
- animate.min.css
- jquery-1.10.2.js
- bootstrap.js
- bootstrap.min.js
- bootstrap-checkbox-radio-switch.js
- bootstrap-notify.js
- bootstrap-select.js
- chartist.min.js
- light-bootstrap-dashboard.js

Dropdown is on the top right corner on the demo.

What am I missing?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: create jsfiddle or codepen

Comment: My question is why it's not working. I will try to create a codepen.

Comment: You have not added your id in drop down container.  `data-target="#navigation-example-2"`.   You need to add this id in drop down container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a Fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/n2szyz5f/1/ and everything works.

Correct version of external ressources were probably missing on your side.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this

```css
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.container a {
    float: left;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
    font-size: 16px;    
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    background-color: inherit;
}

.container a:hover, .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: red;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    float: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <a href="#news">Link</a>
</div>

<h3>Dropdown Menu inside a Navigation Bar</h3>
<p>Hover over the "Dropdown" link to see the dropdown menu.</p>

</body>
</html>
```